# Call to daemon in a /etc/init.d script is blocking, not running in background

Tags: linux, unix, daemon, init.d

I have a Perl script that I want to daemonize. Basically this perl script will read a directory every 30 seconds, read the files that it finds and then process the data. To keep it  simple here consider the following Perl script (called synpipe_server, there is a symbolic link of this script in `/usr/sbin/`) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $continue = 1;
$SIG{'TERM'}  = sub { $continue = 0; print "Caught TERM signal\n"; };
$SIG{'INT'} = sub { $continue = 0; print "Caught INT signal\n"; };

my $i = 0;
while ($continue) {
     #do stuff
     print "Hello, I am running " . ++$i . "\n";
     sleep 3;
}
```

So this script basically prints something every 3 seconds.

Then, as I want to daemonize this script, I've also put this bash script (also called synpipe_server) in `/etc/init.d/` :

```
#!/bin/bash
# synpipe_server : This starts and stops synpipe_server
#
# chkconfig: 12345 12 88
# description: Monitors all production pipelines
# processname: synpipe_server
# pidfile: /var/run/synpipe_server.pid
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

pname="synpipe_server"
exe="/usr/sbin/synpipe_server"
pidfile="/var/run/${pname}.pid"
lockfile="/var/lock/subsys/${pname}"

[ -x $exe ] || exit 0

RETVAL=0

start() {
    echo -n "Starting $pname : "
    daemon ${exe}
    RETVAL=$?
    PID=$!
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch ${lockfile}
    echo $PID > ${pidfile}
}

stop() {
    echo -n "Shutting down $pname : "
    killproc ${exe}
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
        rm -f ${lockfile}
        rm -f ${pidfile}
    fi
}

restart() {
    echo -n "Restarting $pname : "
    stop
    sleep 2
    start
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    status)
        status ${pname}
    ;;
    restart)
        restart
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    ;; esac

exit 0
```

So, (if I have well understood the doc for daemon) the Perl script should run in the background and the output should be redirected to `/dev/null` if I execute :

```
service synpipe_server start
```

But here is what I get instead :

```
[root@master init.d]# service synpipe_server start
Starting synpipe_server : Hello, I am running 1
Hello, I am running 2
Hello, I am running 3
Hello, I am running 4
Caught INT signal
                                                           [  OK  ]
[root@master init.d]#
```

So it starts the Perl script but runs it without detaching it from the current terminal session, and I can see the output printed in my console ... which is not really what I was expecting. Moreover, the PID file is empty (or with a line feed only, no pid returned by *daemon*).

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

EDIT : maybe I should say that I am on a Red Hat machine.

```
Scientific Linux SL release 5.4 (Boron)
```

Would it do the job if instead of using the daemon function, I use something like :

```
nohup ${exe} >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

in the init script ?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you daemonize the perl script directly instead of adding the extra layer of the redhat init script `daemon` function.  It's hard to get daemons right if you try to write them on your own. [Proc::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~deti/Proc-Daemon-0.14/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod) is pretty straightforward.

Also, here's a discussion of [how to write perl daemons](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=478839).

Bonus answer: use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) and [Proc::Daemontools](http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Proc-Daemontools-1.06/Daemontools.pm).  That provides a comprehensive daemon management system and you probably already have daemontools installed anyway.  Some people dislike daemontools but it gets the job done.

No matter how many time I write daemon is still seems weird.  Maybe I should just use dæmon.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Debian and its derivatives, use `start-stop-daemon` with -b option to start your process without problem.

Comment: This is RedHat machine, so should use `daemon` and `killproc` instead

Comment: This solved my issue today. In Ubuntu, I copied /etc/init.d/skeleton and couldn't figure out why it wasn't running in the background. I assumed it was already set up for background, but turns out it is not.